# regular expression to remove HTML tags

Tags: c#, html

I have the following expression to strip HTML tags away from data retrieved. How may i edit it to filter out special characters as well? (eg.  , @amp; etc)

Currently it only filters out <>.

@ Page.xaml.cs:

//remove HTML from string with Regex.

```
  public static string StripTagsRegex(string source)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
    }
```

Comment: This regular expression is flawed; it can remove things other than complete HTML tags.  [You cannot parse HTML with a regular expression.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)  No, really.  Don't do it.  Use a proper parser.

Comment: That would not work for a tag like: `<div class='>l'>`

Comment: @mike: Have you tried the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) yet?

Comment: @ BalusC & cdhowie: Thank you to both of you. I did try the HTMLTextBlock parser which did not work in my case. Which is why i had to resort to this. If you would kindly look at my thread to find out the cause of the problem, much appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996533/htmltextblock-which-parses-html

Comment: @ cdhowie: yes i did look into Agility Pack & HtmlUtility. Do not know how to implement it in my case, did try though.

Comment: Take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack for HTML agility pack usage.

Comment: @ Nithin Philips: Thank you for the suggestion. Did try that out though, the closest i could get is by the html parser or by using regular expression. Looks like i have to revert to the former method, which can't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. Use HTML parser, and once you fed HTML into it, then get InnerText (not html) of it. This way you get only content of the html.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually i know the regular expression is not a good approach. Now i guess i've no choice to revert to the former method i tried - the HTML parser which i could not get it to work :( please take a look @ this if you dont mind - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996533/htmltextblock-which-parses-html

Comment: @mike868686, I am sorry, but I don't know this parser, I use HTML Agility Pack, which has several bugs, but when I need I can apply a workaround, quite easily.